# Prove that this space of sequence is measurable

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-analysis, measure-theory

Let $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}} = \prod_{i \in \mathbb{N}} \mathbb{R}$ and suppose $\mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$ is product $\sigma$-algebra of Borel sets in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$ For $m \in \mathbb{Z}$, define $$s_{m} := \{x \in \mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}, \hspace{0.1cm} \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n^{2m}|x_{n}|^{2} < \infty\},$$ and let $$s' := \bigcup_{m \in \mathbb{Z}}s_{m}.$$

How can I prove that $s'$ is a measurable set in $\mathbb{R}^{\mathbb{N}}$? I really don't know where to start. Thanks for your help!

Comment: what do you know about measurability for a countable union? how is the product $\sigma$-algebra in this case defined? Sometimes it helps to add these things to the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's probably a big mess the first time you have to work with infinite product $\sigma$-algebras. There's really not much to do except reduce your sets to statements about finite dimensional distributions.
Note that, for given $m\in \mathbb{Z},$ we have

$$
s_m=\bigcup_{K=1}^{\infty} \left(\bigcap_{N=1}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{n=1}^N n^{2m}|x_n|^2<K\right)\right),
$$
Now,$
\left(\sum_{n=1}^N n^{2m}|x_n|^2<K\right)
\in\mathcal{B}^{\mathbb{N}}$, since it's the pre-image of a Borel-set ($[0,K)$) of a measurable function of the first $N$ coordinates.

Hence, this is a countable union of a countable intersection of measurable sets, so each $s_m$ is measurable, and hence, $s'$ is.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $x \to x_k$ is a measurable function  for each $k$. Hence $\{x:\sum_{n=1}^{M}n^{2m}|x_{n}|^{2} \leq N\} \}$ is a Borel set for each $N$ and $M$.  Now take the intersection over $M$ and union over $N$ and $m$.